# ssh-keyscan has no output

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have server script that automatically pulls down and installs a github repository. As part of the script, I'm running `ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` as the git user to automatically accept github's RSA key prior to checking out the repo.

I have successfully used this same script in a local vagrant instance, as well as on several servers. However, on one of the servers this doesn't work, because `ssh-keyscan -H github.com` doesn't return any output (I've tried this as the git user, my personal user, and as root, and the command acts the same). I can ping github.com, so it's not a connection issue; I can also run ssh-keyscan successfully on another server in the same network. I've tried upgrading SSH to see if that might be the issue, but it is already on the latest version for my distribution (CentOS 7).

Where would be a good place to start in troubleshooting this? I've tried searching StackExchange for issues related to 'ssh-keyscan', but I haven't yet found anything that fits this particular problem.

Comment: Update: I have also removed and reinstalled (and restarted) SSH. The problem remains. Perhaps this implies a config issue, but I don't see anything unusual in the config files.

Comment: I know this is a bit off topic but in situations where you control the remote server you might want to check whether SSH is listening on IPv6 connections on that server. `ssh-keyscan` prefers IPv6 over IPv4 by default if it's available. And it could be the reason it can't connect.

Comment: To clarify: `ssh-keyscan localhost` gave this error: "write(localhost): Connection refused", but `ssh-keyscan -4 localhost` worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does sound like a network problem to me.

The first thing that I would do is try telnetting to various SSH servers on port 22, something like the following:

`$ telnet local-git-server 22`

followed by:

`$ telnet github.com 22`

When you run this, you should see similar output to the following:

`Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2`

This is a good indication that `ssh` is permitted without any firewall restrictions.

- What was the end result from `ssh-keyscan`?
- What did it print, if anything?
- Does the telnet hang for several seconds? Do you get a connection refused or connection rejected response?
- If you run `netstat -an --tcp` do you see several TCP entries that are in SYN_SENT state? If so, this would indicate there is something blocking at the network layer

Comment: Running `telnet github.com 22` results in a 'Connection refused' message, which doesn't happen on the other servers. Running `netstat -an --tcp` does not reveal any SYN_STATE entries. As for the output of `ssh-keyscan`, there is absolutely no output -- no error messages, no warning messages, nothing.

Comment: If you're getting connection refused then you need to look into the network layer. Could your machine or LAN firewall be blocking? Could github.com be refusing?

Comment: I don't think github.com is refusing, but thanks for your point in the right direction. Instead of looking on the machine itself, I suspect I now need to contact the network team to find out what's going on from their end. Thanks!

Comment: I definitely have a 'firewall problem' and I'm very sure that's causing `ssh-keyscan my-host` to output nothing.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue (no output being given) and it was because the default timeout (5 seconds) was too short. I resolved this by using the -T flag which allows me to set my  own custom timeout (in seconds). Illustrative example with 240 second timeout and random IP address:

```
ssh-keyscan -T 240 52.213.86.118
```

Comment: This -- thank you. Feels like a bug that there's no error message on this.

Answer (score 10):

Try running `ssh-keyscan -p <PORT> <IP>` if your ssh server is not running on default port

Comment: This was what I needed. I did not realise that ssh-keyscan does not consult the ~/.ssh/config for "port" lines defined there. ssh-keyscan uses port 22 unless you use -p. It would be nice if the man page said this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i was able to ping the  but

```
ssh-keyscan server IP
```

gave this error:

```
write(localhost): Connection refused
```

The issue in my case was ssh port in that server was open on a different port (7999 in my case) rather than the default 22 as ssh port. Explicitly adding the port number solved the issue. Here is the command that worked for me:

```
ssh-keyscan -p 7999  -T 100 -t rsa -4 server IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I ran `ssh-keyscan github.com`. I tried putting a custom `-T` flag to increase the timeout but there was no output whatsoever. So to debug the problem I ran `ssh -vvv github.com` to connect to github.com on port 22. The `-vvv` gave some debug information and ultimately the command ran to `Operation timed out`. So there might be a few solutions to this. You can ask your ISP provider if port 22 is enabled, or like in my case it was caused by a third party software (Teamviewer). Uninstalling it resolved the problem. This is a solution that helped me but in your case there might be something else involved.